# Selecting English from language selector fails

Tags: i18n-l10n, domain-access

I have setup a multilingual website using the i18n and domain access modules. Each country has its own domain and on a few of these domains multiple languages are available. eg. fr.domain.com has the available languages French, English, German and Dutch with French being the default. When selecting English as a language from the language selector on this French domain the translation fails and instead either loads the domains default language or I receive a 'Page Not Found' error. I have checked that all English content is available on this domain. All other languages translate correctly when selected from the drop down.

I'm really not sure where to go from here as I'm not too familiar with i18n modules so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to Configuration and choose Languages.
- Edit 'English' language
- Add 'en' in 'Path prefix language code' filed
- save and flush all cache